# why UIDatePicker Not Animated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

[datePicker setDate:today animated:YES];
```

When i use This , i have no animating!!
Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and Here doesn't work in viewDidLoad too. In another method works fine. I think is better you change your approach because viewDidLoad is usually used to setup a view.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the date in `viewDidLoad:` sets the date before the date picker appears onscreen. Wait until `viewDidAppear:` before setting it.